# How to write the equivalent query in NEST,C# for the date_histogram by week

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, asp.net-core, kibana, nest

I need to convert the following query into c# in  using NEST.

```
"aggs": {
          "number_of_weeks": {
              "date_histogram": {
                    "field": "@timestamp",
                    "interval": "week"
                  }
                }
     }
```

in Kibana the output is

[image]

I wrote the following query but it give me zero bucket while in Kibana it return many result in buckets

```
var query3 = EsClient.Search<doc>(q => q
                      .Index("SomeIndex")
                      .Size(0)
                      .Aggregations(agg => agg.DateHistogram("group_by_week", e => e.Field(p => p.timestamp) .Interval(DateInterval.Week)
                  )) ;
var resultquery3 = query3.Aggregations.DateHistogram("group_by_week");
```

in  vs studio the output is 
[image]

Comment: May you share `doc` definition? Maybe there is a problem with the mapping field you are using in aggregation `e.Field(p => p.timestamp)`. Maybe you didn't mark `timestamp` property with attribute and NEST is not mapping field name properly.

Comment: Yeah thats was the problem . it fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is likely that

```
e => e.Field(p => p.timestamp)
```

does not serialize to the `"@timestamp"` field in Elasticsearch. For this to work, you would need to either map [it with an attribute on the POCO](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/attribute-mapping.html)

```
public class Doc
{
    [Date(Name = "@timestamp")]
    public DateTime timestamp { get; set; }
}
```

or map it on `ConnectionSettings`

```
var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(pool)
    .DefaultMappingFor<Doc>(m => m
        .PropertyName(e => e.timestamp, "@timestamp")
    );

var client = new ElasticClient(settings);
```

Alternatively, you can simply [pass a string to `.Field()`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/field-inference.html#_implicit_conversion_3), which implicitly converts

```
.Field("@timestamp")
```

Comment: For instance I did the forth one and it worked for me. 
Thanks